# How to securely erase HPA, DCO, and any bad sectors of a SCSI HDD

Tags: hard-drive, dd, secure-erase, wipe, scsi

Does `dd if=/dev/zero of =/dev/cciss/c0d0 bs=1M` wipe over the HPA, DCO, and any bad sectors?

Comment: No.  The whole point of the HPA is that it makes sectors inaccessible.  Likewise the DCO is not accessible either, nor are sectors that have been remapped.

Answer (score 0):

DD cannot erase the HPA or remapped sectors as it can't see them. ATA's secure erase command *should* do this, but there is no way to truly verify that it has been done.